Trying to send RS485 modbus command with PHP and get response into variable
I'm trying to use PHP to send a command to an RS485 modbus device and get the response. I know the device is responding correctly, cable connected correctly, etc, but I cannot seem to get any response from the command sent.
This is the code I am using:
<?php
class rapidserial{
  function _blocking($device,$mode){
      stream_set_blocking($device, $mode);
      return true;
     }
  }
$rapidserial = new rapidserial();
$device = "COM3";
exec("mode $device BAUD=9600 PARITY=n DATA=8 STOP=2");
$comport = fopen($device, "r+b");
if ($comport === false)
    {
    die("Failed opening com port<br/>");
    }
    else
    {
    echo "Com Port Open<br/>"; 
    }
//Set non-blocking mode for writing
$rapidserial->_blocking($comport,0);
$atcmd = "\x0A\x04\x00\x00\x00\x49\x30\x87"; //
fputs($comport, $atcmd);
usleep(10);
// Set blocking mode for reading
$rapidserial->_blocking($comport,1);
echo 'Response:';
$res = fgets($comport, 4017);
fclose($comport);
echo $res;
?>

And attached is the response expected from that command (using a modbus piece of software).
I was expected the response in the echo $res; line but nothing is returned.


"but nothing is returned" - I would encourage not using echo for testing, but something like var_dump or similar. Per the docs, fgets returns a string or false, so your "nothing" might be false, null, an empty string, or possibly whitespace that you can't see. Similarly, fwrite can return false on failure, so it is probably good to inspect that, too.

I haven't touched serial in a very long time, so pardon my ignorance. Does calling exec COM3 with the remaining parameters affect that device in perpetuity at the system level? I'm using to using that function as a one-time-only function, where I need to chain with && or something else in a single command. Also, like my previous comment, it might be worth inspecting the return value of exec.

Totally unrelated to your problem (probably), but I think the rapidserial class is doing more harm than good at this point. You might wrap your logic in an abstraction later, but since this class is currently a single method that does a passthrough without testing the results, and then blindly returns success that you aren't checking, I think it more gets in the way and hides bugs than provides any help. I'd recommend getting functional code working before adding OOP into the mix.

@ChrisHaas Thanks for your replies, very helpful. I did try print_r and also var_dump, print_r also didn't return anything but var_dump returned boolean false. The exec COM3 command returns a correct response showing the COM3 parameters, so this part is working. I also use the same script (to only write a command) so I think I could use it, but I'm not sure how to get the response back from that command. I have tried https://github.com/toggio/PhpSerialModbus but it tells me it's unable to open the port, which I'm not sure I beleive.
